# How do I get the 4 octets of the IP address into a batch *WINDOWS*

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

First of all, sorry for my English.

Hi im looking for a function, variable, or something, but to help me get only the 4 octets of the ip, I am familiar with linux scripts but I can not find a way to cut by the ip in specific. This is because I have to put the information of the equipment as (MAC, COMPUTERNAME, DATE) in a text file, so that each time I do it will be writing line by line.

**At the end** I want something like this, I dont care about the order at the line:

**DATE: 24/05/2018 HOUR :  8:56:20,62 COMPUTER NAME : LZ1710172481 IP : 10.138.53.150**

***So basically I want only the IP (4 octets)***

*Thank you very much in advance.*

**This is the script**

```
@echo off
echo ===========================================
echo         = EQUIPMENT CONFIGURATION =
echo ===========================================
echo\
echo Today's date:% date%
echo.
echo Computer Name:% computername%
echo.
echo IP Address:
ipconfig | find / i "IPv4"
ipconfig | find / i "IPv4" >> \\ 10.138.50.215 \ test \ txtinfo.txt

echo.
echo MAC of the Team:
getmac
echo.
echo DATE:% date% TIME:% time% NAME OF THE COMPUTER:% computername% >> \\ 10.138.50.215 \ test \ txtinfo.txt

echo\
echo Press the "SPACE" key to close this window ...
pause> nul
```

Comment: So. what's your question ?

Comment: well, i want to get the 4 octets of the ip basically. :D

Comment: The current machine may have several network adapters, each with their own IPv4 address. How do you want to handle that? There would also be multiple MAC (Physical Address) for those adapters. Or does `getmac` refer to something about an Apple Macintosh computer?

Comment: Why are you putting spaces in your file paths?

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^|find "IPv4"') do set "ip=%%a"
```

If you need to remove the starting space:

```
set "ip=%ip:~1%"
```

(Note: it's `\\10.138.50.215\test\txtinfo.txt` and `%date%`, `%time%`, `%computername%`)

And in case, you need it too:

```
for /f %%a in ('getmac') do set "mac=%%a"
```